# How do you allow a null date entry with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, null

I'm brand new to ROR.  I'm having a pretty simple problem that I can't find the solution to anywhere.  In one of my projects I have a field to enter the date.  The problem is that for lots of the data that I gather the date is missing.  I don't know how to make that null.  My form.html looks like this.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
```

I imagine that just need to add something to this to allow there to be no date entered.  Does anyone know how to allow null entries in a date field?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following option to allow blanks if that's what you mean:

```
<%= f.date_select :date, :include_blank => true %>
```

You can then leave it blank, so it becomes NULL in your DB.